# Resize font on dragging the slider

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on flutter application and I want to set font size dynamically. I have a screen split in two portions and there is a slider between these two sides. On dragging the slider horizontally one side expand and the other contract. The functionality I want to achieve is to increase/decrease font size on panel expansion/contraction.

Here is the screenshot of my UI design [Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8GFe.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8GFe.png)

Anyone help me please how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic logic/example ! Modify this with your own widgets !
I checked with [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter?null_safety=true) and it works fine !
**(updated)**

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
    }
    
 class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  double wid1 = -1; //Being I used null safety, I initialized these with a random value;
  double maxDx = -1, textSize = 20, prevDx = 0, tmpSize = 0,
  minSize = 15, maxSize=100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (wid1 == -1) {
      maxDx = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      wid1 = maxDx / 2;
    }

    return SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        child: Stack(children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.blue,
                width: wid1,
                child: Text('View 1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
          ),
          Positioned(
              left: wid1,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onHorizontalDragDown: (d) {
                    prevDx = d.globalPosition.dx;
                  },
                  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (d) {
                    if (d.globalPosition.dx < maxDx - 50 &&
                        d.globalPosition.dx > 50)
                      setState(() {
                        tmpSize = prevDx - wid1;
                        wid1 = d.globalPosition.dx;
                        if(tmpSize>minSize && tmpSize<maxSize)
                          textSize = tmpSize;
                        else if(tmpSize<minSize)
                          textSize = minSize;
                        else if(tmpSize > maxSize)
                          textSize = maxSize;
                      });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 15,
                    height: 50,
                  ))),
          Positioned(
              left: wid1 + 15,
              child: Container(
                width: maxDx - wid1 - 15,
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text('View 2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: textSize)),
              )),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to change font size only. The functionality for dragging the slider is already implemented. Now just want to increase font size with expansion and decrease with contraction.

Comment: You have used just a Container widget with one text just for example. But if this widget is a long widget tree with so many Text widgets then the whole widget rebuilds each time with drag position change and text size update. Doesn't it result to slow UI performance?

Comment: You can replace setState with your state management logic !